# How can I defend myself from closure as "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked what I thought was a focused question at [Are there any parallel Russian / Slavonic – English prayer books for Orthodox Christians?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/43451/what-parallel-russian-slavonic-english-prayer-books-for-orthodox-are-there)

From all the digging I've done, I've found one example of a parallel Russian-English translation, and later a second example. Both can be described in a few sentences, and even if one is verbose and finds a scant few more (I doubt that such exist), that's not a lot of terrain to cover, nor is it a lot of words.

What are my defenses here against closure as being too broad? So far as I can see, either a frustratingly scanty set of available resources does not prevent closure as "There are either too many possible answers," or else a topic that does not particularly invite wordy discussion, and more to the point *solicits identification of texts but not discussion or comparison between translations* does not prevent closure as "good answers would be too long for this format."

I've since done research and found a second tolerable translation. But what are my protections against a narrow question being closed as too broad, or else able to appeal a moderator's mistake?

I'd like to be a little more defended. How could I have asked this question to prevent unwanted closure as "too broad"?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it's being re-opened anyway, which is fine.  The only challenge I had with it is that had several people, whether that be three or five hundred, had all found a different reference, each answer would have been equally valid.

From the [help pages](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> **To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …**
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

That said, the community seems to disagree and there are already two re-open votes, and I don't intend to fight to keep it closed.  I'm just explaining why I closed it in the first place.

**Suggestion for the future:**

Phrase it as "Do other such books exist? (Answer is either yes or no) and include "If so, please provide references/examples to back up your "yes" answer.

That falls well within all site guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do originally would have been to make it clear in the question that you had already searched and found few options.  A question like "what are some examples of Spanish-English bibles?" would be extremely broad, and your question at first glance looks similar to that.

Regarding what to do after the question is closed, you may not know that when a closed question gets edited, it automatically appears in a review queue for users to look at again.  In fact, I saw your edits before I saw this meta post, so the system was already working in your favor even before you posted this question.  Still, a meta post like this is also a worthwhile way to get feedback on how to improve a question.

All that said, thank you very much for now making it clear in the question that you are having trouble finding books like this.  I've voted to reopen the question, and I hope you get an answer.